# Is it possible to scale up the number of nodes depending on the real time traffic in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am developing a voting app using Hyperledger Fabric.

In the case of voting, the number of transactions at most is the number of people because each person can vote only one time.

However, we cannot know how many people will vote before voting starts. It makes us prepare unnecessarily many REST servers to cover the total number of people(potential voters) and that increases cost.

So, Is it possible to scale up the number of nodes depending on the real time traffic in Hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest, from what you've said so far, which is not much, it doesn't sound like Hyperledger is actually a good fit for this project.

The whole point is to provide a trusted system where all participants are known. By participants, I mean organisations. An Organisation joins a channel, then it adds peers to it.

REST APIs are built around peers, as in one REST API per peer. So yes, in theory you can scale, just spin up another peer, create the API, etc, all this can be done automatically, via scripts. Your main issues is knowing when there is too much traffic and when to start spinning up new ones. Also, you might spin up a new one, but how is your app supposed to know a new endpoint is available?

I suppose you could build a facade system and when your scripts spin a new peer and expose a new API, at that point this could be reported to the app so it maintains a list of available APIs, it just sounds like a lot of work for virtually no gain.

I have to wonder, why didn't you simply build a normal API, put it in a cloud, let it scale automatically with built-in tools, job done?

All this aside, if it's too late to change now, maybe you can do it in a different way. Your app could be talking to a queuing system and this is the one pushing the votes to a peer, when available. If it's not available, it can wait, it just means the votes will come in a bit later. So your app doesn't directly talk to the REST APIs, sends messages with votes to a queue, then you have another app which monitors this queue and uses the REST APIs, if they are up. You could even implement a system, where you decide how many votes you send in 1 go, over a period of time or whatever. You can still scale your web app so your users don't have any issues with traffic.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, because to do its job, a node (peer or orderer) would need to have all the blocks of the Blockchain.

So, to scale up the node count you'll need to wait until the new nodes replicated the blocks from the other nodes, which will take time.

Another issue is that adding a new peer to a channel is a manual process that requires user intervention.

Comment: this is not accurate, it doesn't have to be a manual process, peers can be added in an automated way as well.

Comment: you can add peers, but you can't add them to channels without putting an admin's private key (which, belongs to a person) into an application. You need to create a signed transaction that adds the genesis block to the channel. In theory you can sign it once, and re-use it, but there is no tooling to do that (unless you write such tooling yourself).